# Including a JAR-file that uses an ini-file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm new to Eclipse and relative new to JAVA-programming. I'm running Eclipse in vmware on my Mac.

I got an API that exists of one JAR file and one ini file. When including my JAR file as a library and calling a method from one of its classes I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: name.ini (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at eu.nets.baxi.log.FileAccess.getIniFileEntryValueStr(FileAccess.java:93)
    at eu.nets.baxi.log.FileAccess.getStringPropetyFromIniFile(FileAccess.java:121)
    at eu.nets.baxi.client.BaxiCtrl.readPropertiesFromIniFile(BaxiCtrl.java:452)
    at eu.nets.baxi.client.BaxiCtrl.open(BaxiCtrl.java:1271)
    at main.main.init(main.java:11)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The documentation for this API says that the ini file should be places in the sam directory as the application executable running "name of the API". I´ve tried a lot of different directories for the ini file but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know what the problem might be? Please tell my if my description is insufficient.

Kind regards / H

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you run the jar while you are in the jars folder.That is, run as

```
java -jar yourJar.jar
```

But if you are running the jar from  another folder, it will fail. For example;

```
java -jar path/yourJar.jar
```

Because, in this approach the path to your ini file will be path/ini. To solve the problem, write a bash script to run your jar always in its folder. Or, change your jar to take input of the file when it is run.